# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'CBPeripheral?'

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ScaningViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
var peripheralDevice: CBPeripheral?
var devicesArray: [String] = []
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

var selectedDevice: String?

@IBOutlet weak var DeviceListTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return devicesArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? DeviceListTableViewCell
    cell?.deviceName.text = devicesArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedDevice = devicesArray[indexPath.item]
    print(selectedDevice!)
    centralManager?.stopScan()
    self.decodePeripheralState(peripheralState: selectedDevice.state)
    self.peripheralDevice = selectedDevice
    self.peripheralDevice?.delegate = self
    print(self.peripheralDevice!)
    self.centralManager!.connect(self.peripheralDevice!)
    }
```

In func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method when I select a row that time i get indexpath.item in string but I want this **selectedDevice** in CBPeripheral type.
Please give me any solution to do this.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: _"I want this selectedDevice in CBPeripheral type."_ If you want it of that type. Then you should create an object of that type instead of `String`. And i just checked the documentation. It seems that `CBPeripheral` has a name property. Is that what you are trying to use?

Comment: UITableView contains string. Try to create another array of CBPeripheral with the peripherals discovered. When the user click on an item on the list, you compare the peripheral name with CBPeripheral.uuid.uuidString (something like this) or with the index and you can retrieve your CBPeripheral object from the CBPeripheral array

Comment: please check my code...i just updated.

Comment: `var devicesArray: [String] = []` => `var devicesArray: [CBPeripheral] = []` `self.devicesArray.append(peripheralName)` => `self.devicesArray.append(peripheral)`, `cell?.deviceName.text = devicesArray[indexPath.item]` => `cell?.deviceName.text = devicesArray[indexPath.item].name`

Comment: create your `devicesArray` of type `[CBPeripheral]` rather than `[String]`.

Comment: @Larme it's working ...thanks